C++ assignment giving random numers and not displaying the inventory from the Inventroy.txt
Working on a C++ assignment and when it displays inventory my CMD shows a bunch of random numbers.
I am trying to get into this format
shea butter 2.00 20 0
mint shampoo 5.00 15 1

//Void from Assignment given
void logo();
void menu();
void writeFile(string itemNames[], double itemCost[], int itemNoShip[][2]);
void displayInventory(string itemNames[], double itemCost[], int itemNoShip[][2]);
bool readInventory(string itemNames[], double itemCost[], int itemNoShip[][2]);

const int MAX = 10;

const string FILE_INPUT = "inputInventory.txt";
const string FILE_OUTPUT = "outputInventory.txt";


int main()
{
    const int MAX = 10;
    string itemNames[MAX];
    double itemCost[MAX];
    int itemNoShip[MAX][2];
    int choice;
    ifstream inputFile(FILE_INPUT, ios::in);
    string line;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        inputFile >> itemNames[i] >> itemCost[i] >> itemNoShip[i][0] >> itemNoShip[i][1];
    }

    do
    {
        logo();
        menu();
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {

        case 1:
            if (readInventory(itemNames, itemCost, itemNoShip))
            {
                cout << "File read succesfully...\n";
            }
            break;
            return 0;

        case 2:
        {
            displayInventory(itemNames, itemCost, itemNoShip);
            cout << "Inventory not yet read from file. Please choose option 1 first." << endl;
        }
        break;

        case 3:
        {
            cout << "File written to outputInventory.txt..." << endl;
            cout << endl;
            writeFile(itemNames, itemCost, itemNoShip); //testing switch statement 3
            break;
        }
        case 4:
            cout << "Invalid Menu Item entered...must enter 1-4..."; //testing switch statement 4
            cout << "Exiting program..." << endl;
            break;

        default:

            break;
        }
    } while (choice != 4);

    return 0;

    inputFile.close();

}
//Missael Ramirez
void logo() {
    cout << "*****************************************\n";
    cout << "           Vander Vormar's Galaxy Diner\n";
    cout << "*****************************************\n";
    cout << "         **         **\n";
    cout << "         **         **\n";
    cout << "         **         **\n";
    cout << "         **         **\n";
    cout << "         **         **\n";
    cout << "          ***********\n";
    cout << "           *********\n";
    cout << "             *****\n";
    cout << "               **\n";
    cout << "*****************************************\n";
}

void menu()
{
    cout << "1.  Read Inventory" << endl;
    cout << "2.  Display Inventory" << endl;
    cout << "3.  Write to file" << endl;
    cout << "4.  Exit" << endl;
}


void writeFile(string itemNames[], double itemCost[], int itemNoShip[MAX][2])
{
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputFile.open(FILE_OUTPUT, ios::out);
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        outputFile << setw(13) << itemNames[i] << setw(6) << itemCost[i] << setw(6);
        outputFile << itemNoShip[i][0] << setw(6) << itemNoShip[i][1] << endl;
    }


}

void displayInventory(string itemNames[], double itemCost[], int itemNoShip[][2])
{
    cout << "Item Name\tCost\tNo.Stock\tShipping (1-Yes 0-No)\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        cout << itemNames[i] << "\t" << itemCost[i] << "\t" << itemNoShip[i][0] << "\t" << itemNoShip[i][1];
    }


}

bool readInventory(string itemNames[], double itemCost[], int itemNoShip[][2]) {
    ifstream inputFile;

    inputFile.open("inputInventory.txt");

    if (inputFile.fail()) {
        inputFile.close();
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        getline(inputFile, itemNames[i]);
        inputFile >> itemCost[i];
        inputFile >> itemNoShip[i][0] >> itemNoShip[i][1];
    }

    inputFile.close();
    return true;
    {
        cout << "File missing!" << endl;



        return true;
    }
}

    inputFile.close();
    return true;
    {
        cout << "File missing!" << endl;



        return true;
    }
}


This is how I want it look like am I doing something very wrong??


Right off the bat, you never check that you opened the file. And then there a a ton of nits that I have with the code. This is C with cout, and that's a terrible way to write C++. Not showing what the input file looks like is not helping anyone. MAX is defined in different scopes, but is the same value. etc.

break; return 0; doesn't do what you think it does. Your menu functionality is split across the function and the main() function.

Minor point: std::ifstream is an input stream; you don't need to tell its constructor that. ifstream inputFile(FILE_INPUT); is sufficient.

And finally, you open the file and read it in main(), and note that the file is still open, you then call a function (when the choice is entered) to read it again. It will fail to open the file. And that's the worst of it, I think.

When you read MAX number of items from the file, you never check that reading them actually succeeds. You just assume that you have successfully read MAX number of items. The output indicates that you have not read a single item successfully from the file. Also, put all item data in a class: struct Item { std::string Name; double Cost; int NoShip; }; and create a function for reading one full item that returns something to indicate if reading the item succeeded or not. You could even overload operator>> for this purpose.

inputFile >> itemNames[i] reads only the first word of each product name. The second word is then read as a double into itemCost[i]. This fails, placing inputFile into a failed state. All subsequent input fails, no variables are updated, and they end up with random garbage values.

Don't use arrays.  Vectors are easier to pass to functions and you can query a vector for its capacity and size; you can't query a passed array for capacity or size.

FYI, in function logo, you can define all that text in one variable (static const char), then use std::cout.write(); to block write to the console (this is very fast).

Okay Okay, I was able to get it to work now. Thank you all everyone you are all blessings.
